# e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un formulario que cree dinámicamente. Luego a los valores que ingresa el usuario los 'pusheo' a un array vacío. El problema que tengo con el preventDefault es que luego de que se ingresan los primeros datos cuando quiero ingresar nuevos datos luego de dar click en el botón de enviar el preventDefault ya no funciona y se reinicia la página. Paso el código a continuación.

````
``` const estudiantes = [];
     class Estudiante {
           constructor(nombre, subject, email) {
               this.nombre = nombre;
               this.subject = subject;
               this.email = email;
    }
}

let actividad3 = document.getElementById('actividad-3');
let form = document.createElement('form');

form.innerHTML = `<input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese nombre">
              <input type="text"  placeholder="Ingrese asignatura">
              <input type="email" placeholder="Ingrese una cuenta de correo válida">
              <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Enviar Datos">`;
console.log(form);
document.body.append(form);



form.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let inputs = e.target.children;
    estudiantes.push(new Estudiante(inputs[0].value, inputs[1].value, inputs[2].value));
    document.body.innerHTML += '<p>Formulario enviado correctamente</p>'
    console.log(estudiantes)
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes al mezclar la función `append` de nodos con la asignación de contenido HTML mediante `innerHTML`.

Tal como dicen en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list) del SO en inglés (traducido):

> Desafortunadamente, la asignación con innerHTML provoca la destrucción
> de todos los elementos hijos, incluso si está intentando
> agregarlos con append. Si desea conservar los nodos hijos (y sus
> controladores de eventos), deberá usar funciones DOM

Si no quieres un comportamiento errático e imprevisible como el que estás teniendo ahora, o bien lo haces todo con nodos mediante **createElement** y **appendChild** para cada input, o bien con *innerHTML* con todo, incluido el form, sobre un elemento que ya exista previo.